# Check if row exists from select count(*),where MS SQL query (asp.net)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, select-query

i just want to set a variable based on if qno field row is empty or not i.e any entry has been inserted earlier or not

**c# code:**

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM " + tname + "WHERE qno = @qno", con99);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qno", qno);
    if ((int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() == 0) //V Studio shows error here
          qno_present = 0;
    else
        qno_present = 1;
```

**Error:**

*an exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='.*

Comment: You are missing a space after your table name. But really this screams of a poor design when you have to pass in the table name. And potentially a sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM " + tname + "WHERE qno = @qno", con99);
```

You need space before the `WHERE` clause

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM " + tname + " WHERE qno = @qno", con99);
```